# Android: How to enable my button back if EditText is not empty?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I have 2 EditTexts; 01 and 02. My button will be disabled once the activity is started and when these two EditText contain text, the button has to be enabled again. However my button is always disabled and can't enable it using `button.setEnabled(true);`.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
summit.setEnabled(false);

buttonEnable();

public void buttonEnable(){
    if (feedback.length()>0 && email.length()>0){
        summit.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        summit.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this,,,but it's still disabled...

Comment: here is my code... i think i need to use TextWatcher... but still can't find out how to use it... x.x
Thx for ur replys... :)

Comment: is feedback and email a textview?

Comment: hmm you could try to use feedback.getText().length()

Comment: Did u put some breakpoint/log just to see if your program call the  buttonEnable() method?

Comment: The question is *when* are you calling `buttonEnable()`? If it's during `onCreate`, then that's useless. You probably want to dynamically monitor the input of the text views.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct about needing a TextWatcher. The `afterTextChanged(Editable)` method is the one you're interested in for something like this. Call your `buttonEnable()` method from it, and add the TextWatcher to any applicable text fields. (Looks like `feedback` and `email` from your sample.)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way can also be to set `onKeyListener` to your `editText()`, then if there is something in `editText()`, set button enable if nothing disable it.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Comment: @meagar : Sorry but i didn't understood where i used it, can you just pin point it, so that in future i can take care of it.......

Comment: Appending a signature like "God bless you" to your posts isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow.